# Robocopy only copy *.vhdx files in root folder

Tags: windows, robocopy

how can I copy with Robocopy only *.vhdx files in the root directory?
It is important to me that the file attribute and secuirty is preserved.

I used

```
robocopy \\Server\Users ServerNew\Users /sec /mir /log:c:\logs\log.txt /v /tee /w:2 /r:0 /copy:DT
```

However, it keeps copying the subdirectories, which I don't want.

Thanks for your support

Comment: You're using the /mir option, which appears to not be what you want. Have a look at the robocopy documentation. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 0):

Use robocopy withour `/mir`, like this:

```
robocopy \\Server\Users \\New\Users /sec /log:c:\logs\log.txt /v /tee /w:2 /r:0 /copy:DT
```

Answer (score 0):

`/mir` implies `/e` (recurse including empty subdirs).

If you want to copy new(er) files and purge removed files in a single directory, just use the `/purge` option instead of `/mir`.

Answer (score 0):

i think the below would work, however you may want to test it, on some test files before you run it. Recommend trying on some dummy text files....  i'm mobile right now.

```
robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination *.vhdx /E /COPY:DATSOU /DCOPY:T /sec
```